# C# Method Overflow

Tags: c#, .net, class, overloading

```
private void btnMiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int milesless200 = int.Parse(txtMiles.Text);
        int milesmore200 = int.Parse(txtMiles200.Text);

        MilesCal workingoutmilescost = new MilesCal();
        if (milesless200 > 200)
        {
            lblMilesMorethan200.Text = "You can't enter more then 200 in the first box";
        }
        else
        {
            if (milesmore200 == 0)
            {
                 int carry = workingoutmilescost.MilesRepay(milesless200);
                 lblMilesShow.Text = carry.ToString();

            }
            else
            {
                int carry = workingoutmilescost.MilesRepay(milesless200, milesmore200);
                lblMilesShow.Text = carry.ToString();
            }
        }
        lblMilesError.Text = "No Error";
    }
    catch (FormatException fEx)
    {
        lblMilesError.Text = fEx.Message;
    }
}
```

My Defined class of MilesCal

```
 class MilesCal
    {
        public int MilesRepay(int a)
        {
            int x;
            return x = (a*5)/100;
        }
        public int MilesRepay(int a, int b)
        {
            int y;
            return y = (a*5)/100 + (b*2)/100;
        }
    }
```

This code is suppose to display in a label the cost a driver gets back from their driving at 5p for the first 200 miles then 2p after that. I have got the code working but then discovered that it has to be done using Method overflow. at the minute am getting an error Error   1   Cannot convert method group 'ToString' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method? at

```
lblMilesShow.Text = carry.ToString;
```

Added the ().

Now the catch seems to be trippping, can i ask you guys again to work this out because its probably a simple fix again?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  Method overloading.

Comment: The ToString is not a property its a method hence should be ToString(); You are missing the opening and closing braces.

Comment: Darn. I clicked on this question thinking I was going to learn about some programming concept that I'd never heard of before.

Comment: @ean5533 you and me both man.

Comment: @Dan1676, did you edit the question wit the "catch seems to be trippping[sic]" part? You're going to have to add more details, because I for one have no idea what that means. Better yet, ask a new question, since people have already answered for your first problem.

Comment: Yes, a new question is in order for the last sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add brackets

```
lblMilesShow.Text = carry.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `carry.ToString()`, including the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

`ToString` is a method. You need to use brackets. Try `carry.ToString();`

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are all right. `.ToString` is a method. So using the name of the method without invoking it means you are passing a reference to the method group, not doing the *work* of the method itself.

`carry.ToString` is a reference to the function `ToString`

`carry.ToString()` invokes the `ToString` method on the instance `carry`.

---

But, really, I think you are going about this all wrong, instead of having two text boxes you should just have the person enter the number of miles they drove. And then have a function that does this work for you:

```
    public int MilesRepay(int miles)
    {
        return Math.Min(200, miles) * 0.05 + Math.Max(0, miles-200) * 0.02;
    }
```

Or something like that....

Comment: oh... its ***homework***. that or you have the worst employer ever.

Answer (score 1):

```
lblMilesShow.Text = carry.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

ToString is a method.  You need to add parentheses after the name of the method.

```
lblMilesShow.Text = carry.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

ToString is not a property, but a method, invoke with brackets

```
lblMilesShow.Text = carry.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have already reported, you have to use parentheses.

The explanation of the error message "Cannot convert method group 'ToString' to non-delegate type" is, that a method name without parentheses designates the method itself and interprets it as a delegate. It does not call the method. If you want to call the method and use its return value, always use the parentheses!

You can think of a delegate as being the memory address of a method. (In reality, it is an object, which encapsulates this address.)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by

> the catch seems to be tripping

you mean that you catch the exception in the `catch`-block in the bottom. If this is the case you I assume it can only be a parse exception from one of the `int.Parse`-calls. You are trying to parse something that is not an `int` - maybe an empty string??